# FT801 chip id error on Arduino

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller, ftdi, intel-edison

I have an Arduino clone Edison board with an FT801 graphics chip on it. While attempting to run the example sketches with the chip I encounter a chip id error. It's reporting the chip id as 3C074D54 which doesn't match the expected FT801 constant of 10108. From what I can tell the ID should be unique so why then would their sample code include:

```
if(FT801_CHIPID != chipid)
```

Could it be a counterfeit chip?

Stephen

Comment: I don't know if can be a counterfeit or simply is a different chip. What the Arduino clone Edison datasheet say?

Comment: Well the datasheet isn't written but the guy who designed the board says to just comment out the check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be when they tested the sample code, they used a chip whose ID was 10108 but on the actual board they are using the different chip. They said rightfully..You need to comment out that line to reject any chip ID checking mechanisms. Moreover you can also edit the firmware to suit your chip ID..but before doing that please read its data sheet properly and if possible then try to cross check it several time before updating your firmware.